# Hashing Serialized in Silverlight

Tags: c#, serialization, hashcode

I have a Silverlight app. This app calls back to a web service (that I've written) to get a list of customers. I'm trying to generate a hash code that represents the list of customers. In an attempt to do this, I have the following code written in my Silverlight app, and in my server-side code:

```
public static string GetHashCode<T>(T data)
{
  SHA256Managed crypto = new SHA256Managed();
  try
  {
    // Serialize the object
    byte[] serializedBytes;
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
      serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, data);
      memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      serializedBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    byte[] hashed = crypto.ComputeHash(serializedBytes);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hashed.Length; i++)
      sb.Append(hashed[i].ToString("X2"));
    return sb.ToString();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    return string.Empty;
  }
}
```

My method on the server-side looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Customer> GetCustomers() 
{
  List<Customer> customers = Customer.GetAll();
  string hash = GetHashCode<List<Customer>>(customers);
  return customers;
}
```

On the client-side, in my Silverlight app, I have the following in my GetCustomersCompleted event handler:

```
string hash = GetHashCode<List<Customer>>(e.Result.ToList());
```

Please notice that I am converting the event handler Result to a list first. The reason why is because the Result is actually a ObservableCollection. I bring this up because I believe this is where my problem lies.

My problem is, even though the data is the same, my hash values are different on the server and client-side. This is based on what I'm seeing in the watch window. I have a feeling it has something to do with the serialization that occurs when the results get passed from my server to my app. However, I'm not sure how to get around this. I need a hash of the data, but I can't figure out how to get them to line up. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why?

Comment: Before looking at the hashig: have you compared the serialized bytes first? I'm not sure that DCS promises to use the exact same layout: just that it will be compatible.